# why does fread from stdin not stop

Tags: c, file, pointers, fwrite, fread

I am trying to read input from `stdin` with `fread()`. However i am have a problem, the loop will not terminate and instead keeps reading.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "argument err");
        return -1;
    }
   
    FILE *in  = fopen(argv[1], "w");

    if (in == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file");
        return -1;
    }
   
    char buffer[20];
  
    size_t ret;

    while ((ret = fread(buffer, 1, 20, stdin)) > 0) {
           if (fwrite(buffer, 1, ret, in) != ret) {
               if (ferror(in) != 0) {
                    perror("write err:");
               } 
           }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

How can i make this loop terminate when EOF is reached? i have tried using ctrl+D but that just seems like a strange way to stop taking input.

I guess what i want is to use fread() to read multiple arbitrary amounts of data in chunks of 20 bytes and then somehow stop.

Comment: How to make the loop terminate? `break` and `return` sound good.

Comment: Press `CTRL`+`D`

Comment: As for 'why doesn't the loop terminate': fread will never return '0' unless it encounters an EOF. Since stdin is an 'eternal stream' (the `read` blocks, right?), you never get the '0' and thus it will keep going forever.

Comment: Or `CTRL`+`Z` (on a new line) in Windows.

Comment: `CTRL` + `C` is also a classic.

Comment: On another note, naming an *output* file stream `in` doesn't seem very logical.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Except it forcibly kills the program, possibly leaving some data unwritten.

Comment: It is a system issue, not an fread issue.  Insertion of EOF into the console stream is system dependent.  On Windows it is `Ctrl+Z<newline>`.

Comment: Re “i have tried using ctrl+D but that just seems like a strange way to stop taking input”: How do you expect the computer to know when you have entered all the input you want to provide to the program?

Comment: "[I] have tried using ctrl+D", and that is the POSIX (e.g. Linux and macOS) standard way to actually send `EOF` to the application. That's what it's specified to do.

Comment: IMHO it is a bit strange to name an output variable (as you are writting to it) `in` in the code.  Are you trying to make your program unreadable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i make this loop terminate when EOF is reached?

When do you think EOF is reached?  Really.  When you are providing input interactively, how is the system or the program supposed to know that you've entered all the data you want the program to consume?

> i have tried using ctrl+D but that just seems like a strange way to stop taking input.

It is *exactly* the way to signal a soft EOF to a POSIX terminal.  Since you want the loop to stop when EOF is encountered, it seems absolutely natural to me to use ctrl+D for the purpose when providing data interactively.  That's not the only way you could signal the end of the input, but it has a lot going for it.

> I guess what i want is to use fread() to read multiple arbitrary amounts of data in chunks of 20 bytes and then somehow stop.

Again: how is the program supposed to know when it has consumed all the "multiple arbitrary amounts" of data that you decide to provide on a given run?  An EOF signal is an eminently reasonable choice for multiple reasons, and the way to deliver that from a POSIX terminal interface is ctrl+D.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out before you are reading from an eternal stream, this means that `stdin` don't naturally have a EOF (or <=0) value.

If you want your loop to terminate, you will have to add a termination condition, like a certain character, word or all type of value. After that you could use a `break` or a `return` in some case. You could also search if your terminal emulator support the insertion of an EOF value into the stdin, which is pretty common (But very platform dependent).

ADD: On my system, typical linux, CTRL+D is for an EOF insertion in stdin. It seems that you found this out yourself, and if you want your program to know where to stop you will need to use this.

You cand also send a signal to your program, usually done with a shortcut like CTRL+D, CTRL+C, CTRL+T etc... there is all sort of signal, which can be sent by your system or/and your TE and you just have to implement in your program the corresponding signal receiver.

Comment: `EOF` is not a byte character, that can be inserted in the input.  But a completely different value (not a byte, but an `int` value, different to any of the 256 values that can be in a `char`)  IMHO you have a wrong idea of what `EOF` is.  it is used as some means to indicate that an end of file condition has been detected (which consists of reading actually zero characters from the `read()` system call) and not something that gets inserted in the data stream.

Comment: BTW, Control-D doesn't send any signal, but is interpreted by the tty driver, which results in giving to the process the already gathered data, by first deleting the Ctrl-D from the data stream.  So nothing is inserted, but on the reverse, it is deleted from the input stream.

Comment: I didn't mean to say that Ctrl-D send a signa, mybad. For the `EOF` I was aware that it is just a return code placed after the last byte of a file to indicate its end on reading, and not a real value stored in the file or the stream. My answer is not very clear on this, thanks for your correction, I'll do further research to understand best what I was talking about.

Answer (score -1):

> How can i make this loop terminate when EOF is reached? i have tried using ctrl+D but that just seems like a strange way to stop taking input.

`fread` and `fwrite` are there to read data records, so they (both) take the number of records to read and the size of the record.  If the available data doesn't fit on a full record, you will not get the full record at all (indeed, the routines return the number of full records read, and the partial read will be waiting for the next `fread()` call.)

All the calls in `stdio.h` package are buffered, so the buffer holds the data that has been read (from the system) but not yet consumed by the user, and so, this makes me to wonder *why are you trying to use a buffer to read data that is already buffered?*

`EOF` is produced when you are trying to read one record and the `fread()` call results in a true end of file from the system (this normally requires two calls, the first to complete the remaining data, the second resulting in no data ---zero bytes--- returned from the system) So you have to distinguish two cases:

- `fread()` returns 0 in case it has read something, but is not enough to complete a record.
- `fread()` returns `EOF` in case it has read nothing (the true end of file is reached)
  As I've said above, `fread()` & `fwrite()` will read/write full records (this is useful when your data is a `struct` with a fixed length, but normally not when you can have extra data at the end)

The way to terminate the loop should be something like this:

```
    while ((ret = fread(buffer, 1, 20, stdin)) >= 0) {
           if (fwrite(buffer, 1, ret, in) != ret) {
               if (ferror(in) != 0) {
                    perror("write err:");
               } 
           }
    }
    /* here you can have upto 19 bytes in the buffer that cannot
     * be read with that record length, but you can read individually
     * with fgetc() calls. */
```

so, if you read half a record (at end of file) only at the next `fread()` it will detect the end of file (by reading nothing) and you will be free of ending.  (beware that the extra data that doesn't fill a full buffer, still needs to be read by other means)

The cheapest and easiest way to solve this problem (to copy a file from one descriptor to another) is described in K&R (in the first edition) and has not yet have better code to void it, is this:

```
int c;
while ((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF)
    fputc(c, out);
```

while it seems to read the characters one by one, it actually makes a call to `read(2)` to completely fill a full buffer of data, and return just one character, next characters will be taken from the buffer, saving calls to `read()`, and the same happens to `fputc()` (it fills the buffer until it's full, then flushes it, in a single call to `write()`).

Many people has tried to defeat the code above, without any measurable gain in efficience.  So, my hint is *be simple*, that the world is complicated enough to force you to go complex.

Comment: "fread() returns EOF in case it has read nothing" --> No.  `size_t fread()` never returns a negative like `EOF`.

Comment: Let me check.  I'm not sure... I normally don't use neither.

Comment: "All the calls in stdio.h package are buffered" --> Too sweeping. If a stream is buffered or not depends on a number of implementation defined issues.

Comment: well, you are rigth there.... but the default is to buffer somehow.

Comment: There is no _default_ buffering specified by C.  Line buffering is common practice though.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, sorry, I've not said that `fread()` returns `EOF`, but EOF can happen at any point int he file... even in the middle of a record.  `fread()` returns the actual number of full records read, and the rest remains in the buffer.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, not exactly.  Common is to line buffer on ttys, but do full buffering on pipes, sockets, etc.  Also `stderr` is normally not buffered, but `stdout` is.  This practice comes from UNIX, so it will probably be supported in POSIX.